# Loop between 2 short functions

Tags: c

I wrote 2 functions:
`PrintIdentical` -receives 2 arrays and their sizes - sorts them and than call to function
bin_search_print that needs to search each element from the small array inside the big array and print it if found.
i have a bug - the bin_search_print function found the first element and print the first element in a loop and not reaching the other elements.

```
void bin_search_print(int key,int *a,int n)
{
    int low,high,mid;
    low=0;
    high=n-1;
    while(low <= high)
    {
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        if(key==a[mid])
            printf ("%d", mid);
        return mid;
        else if(key<a[mid])
            high=mid-1;
              else   /* key >a[mid] */
            low=mid+1;
    }
    return -1;
}

void PrintIdentical(int arrA[], int arrA_size, int arrB[], int arrB_size)
{
    int i;
    int smaller;
    int *newarr;
        merge_sort(arrA, 0, arrA_size);
        merge_sort(arrB, 0, arrB_size);

         if(arrA_size>arrB_size)
         {
          smaller=arrB_size;
                 for(i = 0; i < smaller; i++) {     
                    bin_search_print(arrB[i], arrA, arrA_size+1);
                 }
         }
         else
          {
          smaller=arrA_size;
                 for(i = 0; i < smaller; i++) {     
                    bin_search_print(arrA[i], arrB, arrB_size+1);
                 }
         }
```

}

```
A[1,2,3,4,5]
B[1,4,3,9]
```

I need to print `1 4 3`

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger; my vote goes to `gdb`. Why return `-1` from a `void`-function?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the loop in the function. Hopefully seeing the variables change will show you what the error might be.

Comment: i used the debugger  - and i couldnt find the reason - i just know from the debuger that the problem is in the binary function

Comment: This needs to be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bin_search_print is missing a return after the printf.

```
if (key == a[mid]) {
  printf("%d", key);
  return;
} else {
  if (key < a[mid]) {
    high = mid - 1;
  } else {
    /* key > a[mid] */
    low = mid + 1;
  }
}
```

Additional notes:
bin_search_print is declared as void and should not return a value.

Please use curly braces with your `if` statements!

Please turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: ok sorry that was the wrong return - please explain why return; and not return 1; or return 0; or return mid; ?

Comment: A function with return type `void` cannot return a value.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't exit from the loop once you've found your key.

```
while(low <= high)
{
    mid=(low+high)/2;
    if(key==a[mid])
        printf ("%d", key);   //<-- okay found key, now look carefully at the logic
    else if(key<a[mid])
        high=mid-1;
          else   /* key >a[mid] */
        low=mid+1;
}
```

Comment: I hope you added the curly brackets!

Comment: printf ("%d", mid);
        return mid;